# Exposing only important logic to the user from a method

Tags: c#, dataframe, .net-5

`RsiStrategy` is a class that should be modified by the user, so it suits his desires. Having that loop and for ex. `if (i < StartupCandleCount - 1)` exposed to the user, is not so great, because the user doesn't care about it. What the user cares about, is the indicators population and buy/sell conditions. Could you guys suggest to me a way to deal with that?

```cs
public interface IStrategy
{
    IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : IStrategy
{
    public abstract IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles);
}

public class RsiStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    public override IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles)
    {
        var result = new List<TradeAdvice>();

        var rsiPeriod = 4;
        var rsi = candles.Rsi(rsiPeriod);

        for (int i = 0; i < candles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < StartupCandleCount - 1)
                result.Add(TradeAdvice.WarmupData);
            else if (rsi[i] < 45 && rsi[i] > rsi[i - 1])
                result.Add(TradeAdvice.Buy);
            else if (rsi[i] > 70)
                result.Add(TradeAdvice.Sell);
            else
                result.Add(TradeAdvice.NoAction);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Expected

I expect something like the following and the logic about `if (i < StartupCandleCount - 1)` and that loop should probably be moved to the abstract class.

```cs
private void PopulateIndicators()
{
    var rsi = candles.Rsi(14);
    var ema = candles.Ema(6);

    // these have to be returned somehow
}

// TODO: I could of course pass current and previous item to the method,
// but I want to be access anything, e.g. rsi[i - 42]. That's basically shifting right
public void BuyCondition()
{
    return rsi[i] < 45 && rsi[i] > rsi[i - 1])
}

public void SellCondition()
{
    return rsi[i] > 70;
}
```

Comment: How many strategies are there? If you have only a few of them I wouldn't bother with additional code that is meant to reduce code (but accomplishes the opposite). Don't over-engineer it.

Comment: @Dialecticus, around 10 for now. But there are around 50 that I didn't add yet.

Comment: And for all 60 of them the code should ignore first `StartupCandleCount` items of input?

Comment: @Dialecticus, yes, because for ex. Exponential Moving Average indicator requires the result from the previous candle EMA, which means the first candle won't be accurate at all. After a few calculations (usually around 100) for period of 14, it gets accurate. The inaccurate results should be truncated. The number of the inaccurate results is set by a property StartupCandleCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to have all strategies implement an abstract method from `StrategyBase`, `public abstract TradeAdvice Advise(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles, int index);`

`StrategyBase` would generate the warmup data trade advices, and run the loop for the rest and call `Advise` for each item. Every strategy would implement just this `Advise` method, and `Prepare` should be implemented by `StrategyBase` only.

With `index` parameter the strategy knows for which item it is giving the advice.

If there is some preparation required before the loop runs there should be a `protected abstract void StrategyBase.Prepare` method. But then the method of the interface should be renamed to something like `Run` or `Execute`. So:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Execute(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : IStrategy
{
    protected abstract void Prepare(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles);
    protected abstract TradeAdvice Advise(int index);
    
    public IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Execute(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles)
    {
        // Call Prepare once, fill up WarmupData, call Advise once per the rest of the items
    }
}

public class RsiStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    protected override void Prepare(IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> candles)
    {
        // Calculate rsi and save it and all the rest to class fields
    }
    
    protected override TradeAdvice Advise(int index)
    {
        // return advice using index and class fields
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What about the indicators tho? The advices are based on `var rsi = candles.Rsi(rsiPeriod);`, etc. I should be able to use them into that method, but they shouldn't be calculated on each loop iteration.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nXkEtmZ6, something like that?

Comment: @nop if it works then yes. If it doesn't work then ask another question. You can give me the link to the new question here.

Comment: It works fine mate, thank you! The only thing I don't like is that I have to expose the indicators to class fields, but I guess that's the only way.